# how to optimize BLOB access with an user defined function

Tags: sqlite

I am storing BLOBs in a sqlite3 database table. 
The table is rather simple:

```
create table r (id integer primary_key asc, d blob);
```

I wrote some user defined functions (let's call one of them "udf()") to read specific values out of the blob. When I am using those functions like this:

```
select udf(100,d), udf(200,d) from r;
```

sqlite3 copies the data d internally (with EXPLAIN I find that the vbde creates OP_COPY instead of OP_SCOPY) without necessity. Is it possible to hint the parser to re use the column d for both calls to udf() instead of copying it (and all the blob data)) (1)?
I already marked the function with SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC in the call to sqlite3_create_functionv2.

(1) https://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html#Copy states "a duplicate is made of every string or blob."

Comment: Could you post the source (or a reduced working version) of the udf and the whole explain+select? Just to make a comparison in order to narrow down the issue, does replacing the "udf(100,d),udf(200,d)" with a "substr(d,100,lenght),substr(d,200,lenght)" result in the op scopy being chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By comparison between user defined and standard sqlite functions behavior, I suspect that the Copy op code could derive from other causes than the udf (like a grouping for example).
You didn't specify the source of your `udf`, so I will proceed to a *reductio per absurdum* assuming that `udf(d,i) = substr(d,i,5)`so:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "udf", Arguments = 2, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
public class Udf : SQLiteFunction
{
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        string res = args[0].ToString();
        int start = int.Parse(args[1].ToString());
        res = res.Substring(start, 5);
        res = res.ToUpper();

        return res;
    }

}
```

The caller demo code is:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(
  @"Data Source=C:\sqlite\test.s3db");
            sqLiteConnection.Open();
            SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(Udf));

            //explain select
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("explain select udf(d,2) from test_blob;", sqLiteConnection);
            //SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("explain select substr(d,2,5) from test_blob;", sqLiteConnection);
            SQLiteDataReader DR = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DR[0].ToString() + ": " + DR[1].ToString() + ": " + DR[2].ToString()
                    + ": " + DR[3].ToString() + ": " + DR[4].ToString() + ": " + DR[5].ToString());
            }

            //sqLiteConnection.UnRegisterFunction(function);
            sqLiteConnection.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

You see no Copy in the output

```
0: Init: 0: 9: 0:
1: OpenRead: 0: 2: 0: 2
2: Rewind: 0: 7: 0:
3: Column: 0: 1: 2:
4: Function: 2: 2: 1: udf(2)
5: ResultRow: 1: 1: 0:
6: Next: 0: 3: 0:
7: Close: 0: 0: 0:
8: Halt: 0: 0: 0:
9: Transaction: 0: 0: 1: 0
10: TableLock: 0: 2: 0: test_blob
11: Integer: 2: 3: 0:
12: Goto: 0: 1: 0:
```

while if you introduce `a group by substr(d,7,1);` in the select

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("explain select udf(d,2) from test_blob group by substr(d,7,1);", sqLiteConnection);
```

that causes a Copy to happen (and not the udf itself, same thing if you replace the udf with a standard sqlite function like substr)

```
0: Init: 0: 41: 0:
1: SorterOpen: 1: 2: 0: k(1,B)
2: Integer: 0: 3: 0:
3: Integer: 0: 2: 0:
4: Null: 0: 6: 6:
5: Gosub: 5: 38: 0:
6: OpenRead: 0: 2: 0: 2
7: Rewind: 0: 14: 0:
8: Column: 0: 1: 10:
9: Function: 6: 10: 8: substr(3)
10: Column: 0: 1: 9:
11: MakeRecord: 8: 2: 13:
12: SorterInsert: 1: 13: 0:
13: Next: 0: 8: 0:
14: Close: 0: 0: 0:
15: OpenPseudo: 2: 13: 2:
16: SorterSort: 1: 40: 0:
17: SorterData: 1: 13: 2:
18: Column: 2: 0: 7:
19: Compare: 6: 7: 1: k(1,B)
20: Jump: 21: 25: 21:
21: Move: 7: 6: 1:
22: Gosub: 4: 32: 0:
23: IfPos: 3: 40: 0:
24: Gosub: 5: 38: 0:
25: Column: 2: 1: 1:
26: Integer: 1: 2: 0:
27: SorterNext: 1: 17: 0:
28: Gosub: 4: 32: 0:
29: Goto: 0: 40: 0:
30: Integer: 1: 3: 0:
31: Return: 4: 0: 0:
32: IfPos: 2: 34: 0:
33: Return: 4: 0: 0:
34: Copy: 1: 15: 0:
35: Function: 2: 15: 14: udf(2)
36: ResultRow: 14: 1: 0:
37: Return: 4: 0: 0:
38: Null: 0: 1: 1:
39: Return: 5: 0: 0:
40: Halt: 0: 0: 0:
41: Transaction: 0: 0: 1: 0
42: TableLock: 0: 2: 0: test_blob
43: Integer: 7: 11: 0:
44: Integer: 1: 12: 0:
45: Integer: 2: 16: 0:
46: Goto: 0: 1: 0:
```

**C++/Native/unmanaged version**

Oh... in your question you mentioned `sqlite3_create_functionv2` and `SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC`.

For all the .net developers: here stops the buck, the answer is complete and you can skip this paragraph.

*Everything is invariant* but, just in case you prefer an *unmanaged code* version, here it is:

```
    IntPtr pointer_db;
    string my_db_file = "test.s3db";
    int open_ret_code = sqlite3open(my_db_file, out pointer_db);
    Console.WriteLine("open ret code:" + open_ret_code.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

    udf_delegate my_delegate = my_udf;
    IntPtr pointer_udf = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(my_delegate);

    int udf_ret_code = CreateFunction(pointer_db, "udf", 2, 1 | 0x800, IntPtr.Zero, pointer_udf, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    Console.WriteLine("udf ret code: "+udf_ret_code.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

    string query = "explain select udf(d,100) from test_blob;";
    IntPtr lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(query);
    IntPtr lpLength = new IntPtr(query.Length);
    IntPtr stmHandle;
    IntPtr Tail;
    int qry_retcode;
    try
    {
        qry_retcode = sqlite3_prepare(pointer_db, query, query.Length,
    out stmHandle, out Tail);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("prepare: " + exc.Message);
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("query ret code: "+qry_retcode.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

    for (int i_step = 0; i_step < 90; i_step++)
    {
        int the_row = sqlite3_step(stmHandle);
        Console.WriteLine("the row: " + the_row.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

        if (the_row != 100)
        {
            break;
        }
        IntPtr my_res = sqlite3_column_text(stmHandle, 0);
        string my_str_res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(my_res);
        Console.WriteLine("query result id: " + my_str_res);
        my_res = sqlite3_column_text(stmHandle, 1);
        my_str_res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(my_res);
        Console.WriteLine("query result Op Code: " + my_str_res);

    }
```

Obviously with the corresponding sqlite.dll imports as well as a `delegate` of the udf.

```
       [DllImport("sqlite3.dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_create_function", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int CreateFunction(
            IntPtr dbHandle,
            string functionName,
            int numArgs,
            int textEncoding,
            IntPtr pApp,
            IntPtr xFunc,
            IntPtr xStep, // null
            IntPtr xFinal // null
            );

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int sqlite3open(string filename, out IntPtr dbhandle);
        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_close", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int sqlite3close(IntPtr dbhandle);

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_value_text", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr sqlite3_value_text(IntPtr value);

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_value_int", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr sqlite3_value_int(IntPtr value);

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_result_text", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int sqlite3_result_text(IntPtr context, string msg, int len, IntPtr transient);

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_prepare_v2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int sqlite3_prepare(IntPtr database, string query, int length, out IntPtr statement, out IntPtr tail);

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_step", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int sqlite3_step(IntPtr statement);

        [DllImport("Sqlite3.Dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_column_text", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern IntPtr sqlite3_column_text(IntPtr statement, int columnNumber);

        delegate void udf_delegate(IntPtr context, int argc, IntPtr[] argv);       
        static void my_udf(IntPtr context, int argc, IntPtr[] argv)
{

            IntPtr text_ptr = sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
            string text = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(text_ptr);


            string result = text.Substring(2, 5); //"here is my udf";
            sqlite3_result_text(context, result, result.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
            return;

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but probably other things led to that issue, I updated to a later version (3.8.8.3) of SQLite and it does not show this behavior. It might also be connected to the fact that the table was a virtual table which was working with BLOBs. I was originally using a 3.7 version.